# Ctest: Force each test to run on the same process

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, ctest

Despite what the documentation says running ctest -j1 still spawns a new process to run tests on. This makes debugging extremely hard since I can't attach debugger to a particular process as it keeps changing. I've verified this by printing pid.

I can run the undelying executable but that doesn't repro a flaky bug I'm seeing so I need a way to attach the debugger to the ctest process.

Is there a way I can force it to run on the same process?

Comment: If somehow you achieve that, you may never see the irregularity again. Because depending on how good you write the tests, sometimes just changing the order of tests will trigger bugs. There are some steps you can take to eliminate unrelated factors while testing. First tell your testing framework to do not shuffle tests. Look at your tests and try to find dependencies between them and eliminate that. Use debug out puts to discover a pattern when irregularity emerges. Find the multi-threaded parts of tests. Run the in single thread. And finally hope for the best.

Comment: @user "I can run the undelying executable but that doesn't repro a flaky bug I'm seeing so I need a way to attach the debugger to the ctest process."

Comment: @MohammadRahimi I want my test framework to shuffle the tests so I can catch flaky tests. If tests are meant to be ordered, the testing framework will have a way for you to flag those otherwise it's a bug in the test. I can repeat the test automatically and shuffle them automatically using ctest flags.

Comment: Every test is an **executable**. For run it one should use a function from [exec*](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) family. When use one of those functions, the caller no longer has a control over the process. That is, ctest simply has no other way than calling [fork()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) for every test.